# How to fix "TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null" for typescript react expo

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-typescript

I am getting this error whenever I try to set the value of my TextInput to a state of the code, here is the code for that:

```
<TextInput
 style={styles.inputBox}
 placeholder="Word Here"
 onChangeText={text2 => {
  this.setState({
   text: text2
  });
 }}
 value={this.state.text}
/>
```

here is my entire files code just in case:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import { Header } from 'react-native-elements';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

type prop = {};
type state = {
  text: string,
  displayText: string,
  word: string,
  lexCategory: string,
  def: string,
  isSearched: boolean,
  examples: Array<[]>
}

export default class App extends Component<prop, state> {
  getText = (word: string) => {
    var searchKeyWord = word.toLowerCase();
    var url = "https://rupinwhitehatjr.github.io/dictionary/" + searchKeyWord + ".json"

    return fetch(url).then(data => {
      if (data.status === 200) {
        return data.json();
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }).then(response => {
      var responseObj = response

      console.log(responseObj)

      if (responseObj) {
        this.setState({
          word: this.state.text.toLowerCase(),
          lexCategory: responseObj["definitions"][0]["wordtype"],
          def: responseObj["definitions"][0]["description"],
          isSearched: false
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          word: this.state.text.toLowerCase(),
          lexCategory: "Word not found",
          def: "Word not found",
          isSearched: false
        });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <View>
          <Header
            backgroundColor={'#81007e'}
            centerComponent={{
              text: 'Pocket Dictionary',
              style: { color: '#fff', fontSize: 20 },
            }}
          />

          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputBox}
            placeholder="Word Here"
            onChangeText={text2 => {
              this.setState({
                text: text2
              });
            }}
            value={this.state.text}
          />

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.searchButton} onPress={() => {
            this.getText(this.state.text)
            this.setState({
              displayText: this.state.text,
              isSearched: true
            });
          }}>
            <Text style={styles.searchText}>Search</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <Text style={styles.words}>Word:</Text>
          <Text style={styles.wordResult}>{this.state.displayText}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.words}>Type:</Text>
          <Text style={styles.wordResult}>{this.state.lexCategory}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.words}>Definition:</Text>
          <Text style={styles.wordResult}>{this.state.def}</Text>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputBox: {
    marginTop: 100,
    width: '80%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    height: 40,
    textAlign: 'center',
    borderWidth: 4,
    outline: 'none',
  },
  searchButton: {
    width: '25%',
    height: 55,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    margin: 20,
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  searchText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  words: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'gold',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  wordResult: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Image of the error on the web page:
[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declare state as a variable, it should be in constructor and declared using `this.state` like this :

```js
export default class App extends Component<prop, state> {
  // Declare state with initial value in this constructor
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: "",
      displayText: "",
      word: "",
      lexCategory: "",
      def: "",
      isSearched: false, // set your initial value
      examples: []
    }
  }

  // ... your rest of code
}
```